# HystrixRuntimeException: TestCommand fallback execution rejected

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netflix, hystrix

I am using Hystrix 1.5.5 version. When I do load testing of bigger load like 1000 thread/second, all the requests are going through fallback method. Meanwhile, I am getting below exception too. Why do I get this below exception. Test Command is my custom Hystrix class

```
Caused by: com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: TestCommand fallback execution rejected.
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.handleFallbackRejectionByEmittingError(AbstractCommand.java:1026)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.getFallbackOrThrowException(AbstractCommand.java:858)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.handleThreadPoolRejectionViaFallback(AbstractCommand.java:976)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.access$400(AbstractCommand.java:59)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$12.call(AbstractCommand.java:593)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$12.call(AbstractCommand.java:587)
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:140)
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:72)
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:72)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$3.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1173)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:54)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to check on the maxConcurrentRequests value for both execution & fallback. Below url discusses on this issue.

https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/796